# how to substitute using an existing even terms only?

Tags: calculus, special-functions

if using  $$C_{n}^{(\lambda)}(0)=\begin{cases}&\frac{(-1)^{n}(\lambda)_n}{n!}; n\,\text{even}\\&0;n\,\text{odd}
\end{cases}$$in the following form$$\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{1}a_{i,n}\tilde{C}_n^{(\lambda)}(x)-\tilde{C}_n^{(\lambda)}(0)$$do i say $$\begin{cases}&\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{1}a_{i,2n}\tilde{C}_{2n}^{(\lambda)}(x)-\frac{(-1)^{n}(\lambda)_n}{n!};n\,\text{even}\\&\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{1}a_{i,2n+1}\tilde{C}_{2n+1}^{(\lambda)}(x);n\,\text{odd}\end{cases}$$

Comment: Is it a poor question? any help.

Comment: Hint: 
$$
\frac12\left(1 + (-1)^n \right) = \begin{cases}1,& n\text{ even}\\0,& n\text{ odd}.\end{cases}
$$

Comment: the right-hand side does not depend on n, so it is impossible to tell if I substitute with $2n$ in both sides of the equation in the even case. need more classification if possible. Appreciate your hint anyways:).